# DAT gui controls not showing inside the scene

Tags: typescript, vue.js, three.js

i have a threejs scene initialized inside a modal. I have three point lights added to the scene. I am working in a seperate three.ts file and exporting the functions from there to the modal component. The problem is that when I initialize DAT.GUI controls, they are rendered outside the modal. I have initialized the controls in the same file as all the other threejs components but somehow the controls are rendering outside the modal. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default dat.gui adds itself to the document body. If you'd like to place it somewhere else, you can disable auto-placement and add it to the appropriate parent manually:

```js
const gui = new dat.GUI({autoPlace: false});
const containerEl = document.querySelector('#container');
containerEl.appendChild(gui.domElement);
```